# how do i show part 3? using the previous parts

Tags: real-analysis

This is theorem is from my lecture notes:

> Theorem 4.19. (Tests for Monotonicity)
> Let $f : I \to \mathbb R$ be continuous on $I$, where $I\subset \mathbb R$ is an interval (either $[a,b]$, $(a,b)$, $[a,b)$ or $(a,b]$, with $a < b$), and assume that $f$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$. Then
>
> 1. $f'(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ $\implies$ $f$ is increasing on $I$,
> 2. $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ $\implies$ $f$ is strictly increasing on $I$,
> 3. $f'(x)\leq0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ $\implies$ $f$ is decreasing on $I$,
> 4. $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ $\implies$ $f$ is strictly decreasing on $I$.

The question that I am working on is the following:

Define the function $f : [e,∞) → \mathbb R$ by
$f(x) =  \frac{\ln x}{x}$.

1. Show that $f$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $[e, ∞)$.
2. Use the monotonicity of $f$ to decide which of the values $f(e)$, $f(π)$ is the larger
   one.
3. Use this and the monotonicity of the exponential function to decide which of the two numbers $e^π$, $π^e$ is the larger one.

I have shown, for part (1), that $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $[e,∞)$ and that $f'(x)= \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$, which is less than $0$ for $x\in(0,∞)$, so $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing. For part (2), I have shown $f(π)-f(e)=f'(ξ)(π-e)$. Since $π-e>0$, we have that $f'(ξ)<0$, so $f(e)>f(π)$.

But part (3), I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use my previous work. This is my first real analysis class, so please show all steps. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use mathjax tools for formatting your question. Such questions are not received well by community

Comment: i don't understand what you mean what part of the format is wrong. This is my first question on here btw.

Comment: I don't mean that your question is wrong. I mean you should use mathjax for writing equations. As an example you wrote f'(x)=(1-lnx)/x^2, which will look much beautiful when written as, $f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^{2}}$. Have a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I see. I fixed it is that better

Comment: I mean not only that. Have a look at the link I posted and try to do that for all stuff you wrote.

Comment: what else needs to be changed?

Comment: Part (3) requires no analysis, just algebra. You showed that $f(e)>f(\pi)$. Therefore, $f(e)>f(\pi)\implies \frac{\ln e}{e}>\frac{\ln\pi}{\pi}$. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you very much